# Vertical stretch WebBrowser to fit content inside

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I've been having some issues with the layout of a page when I have a WebBrowser control in it.

Here's the significant portion of my XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,12">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,17,0,12">
        <phone:WebBrowser Name="HtmlBody" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" Margin="12,17,0,28"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

My question is how do I make the WebBrowser streatch. Setting it's properties to auto doesn't help. If I do that it defaults to a height of 0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Grid instead of the StackPanel, and set the height of the second row to "*", like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,12">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,17,0,12">
        <phone:WebBrowser Name="HtmlBody" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red" Margin="12,17,0,28"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Will this work if I add controls below the WebBrowser as well?

Comment: Yes, you will just need to add more rows to the grid, and set the webbrowser to the first row and other elements to other rows.

Comment: Got it. Will try it this evening when I get home.

Comment: For me too it does not work on WP8 - the browser control is completely invisible when I launch the app.

Comment: Has any one got a better answer ?

Comment: Ask a new question, this answer worked back then, maybe your situation is different.