# Resizing WP8 WebBrowser Height to Fit Content

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, autoresize

i have webbrowser control where i am displaying the content.

Here is the code :

```
<Grid MinHeight="80"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Background="Red"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1"
                              Height="Auto"
                              IsScriptEnabled="True"
                              ScriptNotify="webBrowser1_ScriptNotify"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                              Foreground="Black" Width="Auto"></phone:WebBrowser>
        </Grid>
```

In .CS file;

```
   webBrowser1.NavigateToString("<html><head></head><body bgcolor=#d5e1f3><p style=font-family:arial><font size=3><center>" + content + "</center></font></p></body></html>");
```

here content is:

```
  string content = "Which word in the following sentence is the subject?<I>Paris is beautiful during Spring.</I>Which word in the following sentence is the subject Which word in the following sentence is the subject Which word in the following sentence is the subject";
```

But i have searched for this issue and found many posts but none of them works for me:

1) [Vertical stretch WebBrowser to fit content inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394834/vertical-stretch-webbrowser-to-fit-content-inside)

2) http://dan.clarke.name/2011/05/resizing-wp7-webbrowser-height-to-fit-content/

3) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/232eb27e-5a40-4725-a1dd-f68379dc76b7/webbrowser-sizing-to-fit-content?forum=wpdevelop

4) http://i.nt.ro/how-do-you-resize-a-webbrowser-control-to-fit-on-a-html-element/

How to solve this issue ?

**EDIT**

Ok the complete XAMl:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="POCBase.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Name="AppName" Text="" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock Name="PageName" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid MinHeight="80" 
              Grid.Row="1"
              Background="Red"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.80*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Height="60" 
                   Width="60"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="0,0,20,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="Addition Rule "
                       Name="Inilinetext"
                       FontSize="32"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Padding="10,0,0,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       TextAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid MinHeight="80"
              Grid.Row="2"
              Background="Red"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser1"
                              Height="Auto"
                              IsScriptEnabled="True"
                              ScriptNotify="webBrowser1_ScriptNotify"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                              Foreground="Black" Width="Auto"></phone:WebBrowser>
        </Grid>

        <Grid MinHeight="80" 
              Grid.Row="3"
              Background="Red"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.20*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.80*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Height="60" 
                   Width="60"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Margin="0,0,20,0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="Addition Rule "
                       FontSize="32"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Padding="10,0,0,0"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       TextAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Comment: Could you share complete xaml

Comment: @Jaihind don't you think there is enough XAML in this post? that words with background color is html inside webbrowser control, not XAML (just saying, if you missed that info)

Comment: @har07 No not enough because if web browser has auto height width than it inherit height width of its parent(Grid). which has minHeight '80' and placed at Grid.Row="2" that again child of another grid. that's why i want to know Height of Second row of grid.

Answer (score 4):

To make this work your HTML must end with JavaScript which will inform the WebBrowser about document Size.

The code you have provided lacks this script, so no script is processed and `webBrowser1_ScriptNotify` is not fired.

[Here at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/150897/Dynamically-resize-WebBrowser-control-in-Silverlig) is shown how it can look like.

**EDIT**

I've fought with it for a little while and finding Size of rendered Html is not so simple (for me - I'm a complete newbie in JavaScript, so maybe you will have better knowledge).

You can define your `<script>` in html, then at the end run it or define in `body onLoad`:

```
string content = @"Which word in the following sentence is the subject?<I>Paris is beautiful during Spring.</I>Which word in the following sentence is the subject Which word in the following sentence is the subject Which word in the following sentence is the subject";

string newHtmlString = @"<head></head><body bgcolor=#d5e1f3    
      onLoad=""window.external.notify('rendered_height='+document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight);"">
      <div id='content'><p style=font-family:arial><font size=3><center>";

newHtmlString += content + @"</center></p></div></body>";
```

Then after Navigating the following event should change your WebBrowser.Height:

```
private void webBrowser1_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
   string[] valuePair = e.Value.Split('=');
   if (valuePair != null && valuePair[0] == "rendered_height")
      webBrowser1.Height = double.Parse(valuePair[1]);
}
```

Comment: yes i have seen that, but how to apply that to my html string ?can you please help me out ?

Comment: OK, no problem i will wait

Comment: @Goofy It should go like this. Unfortunately I'm not good at JavaScript and finding size of html element may take me a lot of time. Hopefuly this example will help you, and maybe more suitable it will be to ask a question about finding html rendered size with javascript - when you find it, above code will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks i will check once

Comment: `var h = document.getElementById('content').clientHeight;`  from here: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526347/css-javascript-how-do-you-get-the-rendered-height-of-an-element)

Comment: @safetyOtter Thank you. As I was writing the answer I've tried many solutions (offsetHeight, clientHeight, scrollHeight of document, element, body). None of them worked (for me ;) as I would have expected it. The problem, I think, may be with wrapped text, but I'm not good at javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you found this http://dan.clarke.name/2011/05/resizing-wp7-webbrowser-height-to-fit-content/? Works for me.

Make sure IsScriptEnabled is set to true, subscribe to the ScriptNotify event

```
protected void WebBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("called");
    WebBrowser thisBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    int height = Convert.ToInt32(e.Value);
    double newHeight = height * 1.5;

    thisBrowser.Height = newHeight;
    Debug.WriteLine(newHeight.ToString());
}
```

and put his at the end of your html body (the articles does it a bit differently, works for me at the end of the body)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var elem = document.getElementById('content');
    window.external.Notify(elem.scrollHeight + '');    
</script>
```

And make sure you have a div id="content and that the debug messages get writtent to the output.

Comment: Where do i need to add the script which he has given there ? how can i modify my current content, which i have mentioned above, can you please show mw how ?

Comment: I tried it but still the text is cutting, below i have pasted my tried  example with your soultion, please have a look at it

Comment: <html><head>"+
                    "<meta name=viewport content=width=320 /><script type=text/javascript>"+
                    "window.onload = function () {"+
                    "var elem = document.getElementById('content');"+
                    "window.external.Notify(elem.scrollHeight + '');}"+
                    "</script>"+
                    "</head><body bgcolor=#d5e1f3>" +
                    "<div id=content>"+
                    "<p style=font-family:arial></div>" +
                    "<font size=2><center>" + Text + "</center></font></p></body></html>

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and just provide the link for additional reference. If you're not up to this task, you should consider simply [leaving a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment) on the question instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var elem = document.getElementById('content');
    window.external.Notify(elem.scrollHeight + '');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the height from the webview, you can use

`window.external.notify("rendered_height=document.getElementById('yourId').offsetHeight")`

in `body.onload` and `body.onresize`

Here is a complete example of an [AdaptativeWebview](https://gist.github.com/Ouadie/78fc85965ebaf49e06d4) that handle scroll and resize

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).